# How to say 'till the next station'

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm describing a train incident (I've been through) on my blog, but I'm stuck at the above question. I want to say that 'we remained silent till the next station arrived'(n station can't arrive because it's a train which takes you there). and this is how I've stated it.

"Till the next station, we remained silent".

This doesn't sound correct to me.

Please Help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with "We remained silent until we/the train arrived at the next station" - or "...until we were at the next station"?

Comment: "Till the next station, we remained silent" sounds ok to me.

Comment: Speaking 'relatively', from your point of view the station does move towards you, and therefore, in that sense, "the station arrived" is valid.

Comment: **Why** doesn't it sound correct? Does "We remained silent till the next station" sound better, putting the adverbial phrase after the verb? You can leave your reader to infer the verb for *station*.

Comment: My ear would prefer something like "We remained silent until we arrived at [pulled into] the next station.

Comment: Thank you guys.If I rephrase it like "Until the train took its next stop, we remained silent". This sounds okay to me. Is this a correct way. Please confirm.

Comment: @shanky Trains generally 'reach' stops, rather than 'take' them.In this context 'a stop' is a destination, more than a pause in travel. Trains can stop for reasons other than being at a station. 'the train took its next stop' is not idiomatic in British-English, I couldn't swear to use in other Englishes.

Answer (score 1):

> "Till the next station, we remained silent".

This sounds a bit odd to me, so:

> We remained silent till the next station.

There is nothing wrong with either sentence. There is no accounting for why one might "sound OK", or "not quite OK",  to some, but not to others.

Answer (score -3):

"Till the next station, we remained silent" is not correct.

> "**Place and Quantity: Until/Till  not used**

***Until/Till is used only to talk about time. To talk about distance, we use to, as far as or up to; up to is also used to talk about quantity.***

> We walked **as far as/up to** the edge of the forest. (**NOT**, till the edge
>   of the forest)
>
> The minibus  can hold **up to** thirteen people. (**NOT**, until thirteen
>   people)

It is sometimes possible to use until/till before a place name in the sense of 'until we get to....'

> You drive **until** Phoenix, then I'll take over.

From ***Michael Swan's Practical English Usage***".

Comment: It's idiomatic and common to use such expressions as *until London's skyscrapers appear on the horizon*. Although this example contains a verb, *Till the next station* clearly implies the verb. It doesn't have to be stated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I appreciate your help. So, to state it in other way - "Until the train took its next stop, we remained silent". This sounds okay to me. Is this a correct way. Please confirm.

Comment: @shanky: Yes, when unti/till is used, the chief interest is on the point of  time, not the place.

Comment: Thank you. If possible do check out my post. **"You should never try to board a moving train or"** http://wackyincidents.com/you-should-never-try-to-board-a-moving-train-or/

Comment: But the *till phrase* in *Till the next station, we remained silent* can be interpreted as referring to the ***time*** it took to get to the next station.